# How to use SQL BETWEEN Clause and GETDATE function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT j.JobNo, j.JobDescription
FROM Job j  
JOIN Job_Nav n ON j.JobNo = n.JobNo
WHERE n.Blocked = 0 
AND n.[Starting Date] < GETDATE() AND n.[Ending Date] > GETDATE()
```

I want to change **AND n.[Starting Date] < GETDATE() AND n.[Ending Date] > GETDATE()** into BETWEEN clause, can anyone tell me how to use **Between Clause** for above expression.
THANKS

Comment: `And GetDate() BETWEEN n.[Starting Date] AND n.[Ending Date]`

Comment: You can't. `BETWEEN` operates with *inclusive* endpoints. Your comparisons using `<` and `>` make `Starting Date` and `Ending Date` *exclusive* endpoints. There's no way to change `BETWEEN`s behaviour. By the way, you should be aware that `GETDATE()` includes a time component which you might want to consider if the columns just contain date values.

Comment: @Sohail May i ask why ? It's working perfectly isn't it ? Go throuh this to understand which operator you should use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187922(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getdate() between n.[Starting Date] AND n.[Ending Date]`

is the equivalent of

`getdate() >= n.[Starting Date] and getdate() <= n.[Ending Date]`

(note that it is using `>=` and `<=` instead of `>` and `<`)

I assume you want to use `between` to make your code a little more compact and readable, but your code as written isn't a candidate for such a substitution.

Comment: Yes, you're right I can't use BETWEEN, and many thanks for such advise.

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT j.JobNo, j.JobDescription
FROM Job j

JOIN Job_Nav n ON j.JobNo = n.JobNo
WHERE n.Blocked = 0 
AND GETDATE() Between n.[Starting Date] AND n.[Ending Date]`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT j.JobNo, j.JobDescription
FROM Job j  
JOIN Job_Nav n ON j.JobNo = n.JobNo
WHERE n.Blocked = 0 
AND getdate() between n.[Starting Date] AND n.[Ending Date]
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this matters to you, but GETDATE() could potentially return a misleading result since the function includes the time.

Answer (score 1):

You can't as between is inclusive (>=  <=)

[BETWEEN (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx)

> To specify an exclusive range, use the greater than (>) and less than
>   operators (<).

If you need exclusive what you have is clean
I think separate rows is easier to read

```
AND n.[Starting Date] < GETDATE() 
AND n.[Ending Date]   > GETDATE()
```